# How to create a separate file inside each folder using pathlib?

Tags: python, file

Here is a code that randomly writes to a file with filename random1.txt, random2.txt n so on based on the number of files given by the user.
I'm using pathlib to create directories. I want to move these files to each of the directories when I run the script. For ex - When the user gives input 2 for "Enter the number of iterations needed" prompt
The script should generate Sample1 folder and random1.txt should be inside Sample1 folder and Sample2 folder should have random2.txt

````
import os, glob, shutil
import random, getpass
from pathlib import Path
def sample() -> None:
    username = getpass.getuser()
    number_of_iteration = int(input("Enter the number of iterations needed\n"))
    for i in range(1, number_of_iteration + 1):
        file_name = f"randomfile{i}" + '.txt'
        with open('C:/Users/{0}/PycharmProjects/SampleProject/{1}'.format(username, file_name), 'w') as f:
            list_of_something = [something1, something2, something3]
            random_generator_of_something = random.choice(list_of_something)
            for key, value in random_generator_of_something.items():
                        #does something
                    #writes something to the random file.txt
        with open('C:/Users/{0}/PycharmProjects/SampleProject/{1}'.format(username, file_name), 'a') as f:
                    #writes something to the random file.txt
        Path("C:/Users/{0}/PycharmProjects/SampleProject/Sample{1}".format(username, i)).mkdir(parents=True,
                                                                                                         exist_ok=True)

something1 = {
    'a' : 'b'
}

something2 = {
    'c' : 'd'
}

something3 = {
    'x' : 'y'
}```
````

Answer (score -1):

You can try runing this code after your code. This will create folder for every text file and move into it

```
import glob, os
import shutil

folder = r"C:\Users\****\***\SampleProject" #Project folder change this according to your location

for file_path in glob.glob(os.path.join(folder, '*.*')):
    new_dir = file_path.rsplit('.', 1)[0]
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(folder, new_dir))
    shutil.move(file_path, os.path.join(new_dir, os.path.basename(file_path)))
```

You will get something like

[image]

Comment: When Im assigning the `folder = 'C:/Users/{0}/PycharmProjects/SampleProject'.format(username)` its generating a folder for each randomfile that's working perfectly fine but its also making a folder to the file in which I'm writing this code and its also making directories to other .py files. I just wanted the code to create Random1 directory inside C:/Users/{0}/PycharmProjects/SampleProject and put that random1.txt file into it and so on..